# Complexity of comprehension list vs for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two algorithms in Python, which convert a tuple list into a dictionary:

```
  def _prep_high_low_data_for_view(self, low_high_list):
    dates = []
    prices = []
    lables = []
    for (x, y, z) in low_high_list:
        dates.append(x)
        prices.append(y)
        lables.append(z)

    return {'date': dates,
            'price': prices,
            'label': lables
            }
```

The second one being:

```
    def _prep_high_low_data_for_view(self, low_high_list):
    return {'date': [date for date, _, _ in low_high_list],
            'price': [price for _, price, _ in low_high_list],
            'label': [lable for _, _, lable in low_high_list],
            }
```

Both algorithms are equivalent in terms of what they do.
Is it the case that the second algorithm is worse in terms of complexity, because there are three separate list comprehensions?

Comment: List comprehension is a sweetener for the language. In case of difference of your codes, you have 3 loops vs 1 loop. In case of memory it's the same.

Comment: yes you are iterating 3 times. Since data belongs together i d keed them together like in original array

Comment: The two algorithms are of equivalent complexity O(n).  Your preoccupation on the added computations for separate list comprehensions is not related to the complexity because the multiplier is not a factor of the size of the list (n).  What you are looking for is the impact on total time (or space).  So you need to determine T(f1(n)) vs T(f2(n)).   Florian H's measurements provide good practical indications.  Predicting those figures based on the algorithms would require deeper insights on how the Python interpreter processes list comprehensions.

Answer (score 5):

You could build the 3 lists using zip:

```
dates,prices,labels = zip(*low_high_list)
```

placed in a one line function:

```
def third_function(low_high_list):
    return dict.fromkeys(zip(["date","price","label"],zip(*low_high_list)))
```

it will run faster, on average, than second_function() from Florian_H.

**TESTS AND RESULTS:**

```
def third_function(low_high_list):
    return dict.fromkeys(zip(["date","price","label"],zip(*low_high_list)))

def fourth_function(low_high_list):
    dates,prices,labels = zip(*low_high_list)
    return { "date":dates, "price":prices, "label":labels }


lst = [tuple(random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(3)) for i in range(10000)]

from timeit import timeit
count = 1000

t0 = timeit(lambda:first_function(lst), number=count)
print("first_function: ",f"{t0:.3f}","1x" )

t = timeit(lambda:second_function(lst), number=count)
print("second_function:",f"{t:.3f}",f"{t0/t:.1f}x" )

t = timeit(lambda:third_function(lst), number=count)
print("third_function: ",f"{t:.3f}",f"{t0/t:.1f}x" )

t = timeit(lambda:fourth_function(lst), number=count)
print("fourth_function:",f"{t:.3f}",f"{t0/t:.1f}x" )

# first_function:  1.338 1x
# second_function: 0.818 1.6x
# third_function:  0.426 3.1x
# fourth_function: 0.375 3.6x
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

It's basically `O(n)` vs `O(3n)`, but when working with complexities, `O(3n)` is just shortened to `O(n)`.

So yeah, both of these are algorithms with the complexity of `O(n)`, but the first one does three times less operations.

Comment: As shown you need do take into account that list comprehension might be faster than appending to a list

Comment: Hmm good point, now I'm curious whether the first function passes at high `n`. I'll do some tests and report back :P

Comment: Just "no" because O(n) and O(3n) are the same class of algorithms and none is better or worse than the other in any meaningful way.

Comment: @Goyo you are completly right from a computer science perspective their complexity is equal. But you can have "slower" and "faster" equally complex algorithms. And i would not be sure that David meant that question in such a scientific way even though he used the word 'complexity'

Comment: @Goyo As explained in the answer, what are you after?

Comment: @FlorianH Yes but big-O is about complexity. If you want "faster" or "slower" instead you measure as in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Markust Meskanen mentioned the first algorithm should be 3 times faster (less complex) but why not just trying it? Here your code with random values and a time measuring.

```
import random, datetime

def first_function(low_high_list):
    dates = []
    prices = []
    lables = []
    for (x, y, z) in low_high_list:
        dates.append(x)
        prices.append(y)
        lables.append(z)

    return {'date': dates,
            'price': prices,
            'label': lables
            }


def second_function(low_high_list):
    return {'date': [date[0] for date in low_high_list],
            'price': [price[1] for price in low_high_list],
            'label': [label[2] for label in low_high_list],
            }


def second_function(low_high_list):
    return {'date': [date[0] for date in low_high_list],
            'price': [price[1] for price in low_high_list],
            'label': [label[2] for label in low_high_list],
            }


lst = [[random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100)] for i in range(10000)]

print("first_function:")
tmp = datetime.datetime.now()
first_function(lst)
print(datetime.datetime.now() - tmp)

print("\nsecond_function:")
tmp = datetime.datetime.now()
second_function(lst)
print(datetime.datetime.now() - tmp)
```

And voila, the second function is two times faster than the first...

```
[output]
first_function:
0:00:00.004001

second_function:
0:00:00.002001
```

So it seems, even though the second function runs three times instead of one, in this case list comprehension is still twice as fast as looping with appending to a list.

1000 times average is still roughly twice as fast:

```
0:00:00.002820
0:00:00.001568
```